# An Ancient Indus Valley Code

Tags: cipher, letters

> A tourist found a code which seemed very intriguing to him, while visiting a ruined city of the old Indus Valley Civilization. He has a great interest in deciphering ancient codes, but he has a tough time solving this one. So he hires you to help him solve the code for him. The code goes as follows-
>
> H Y Y R E U H U T X R U P H T R R F E : A R O N D

(PS: I don't know the solution to this problem)

Source: Asked in Sphinx 2013(Puzzling event in MNNIT Tech Fest (Avishkar))

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. If you have not done so, please take [the tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). You will get a badge.

Comment: Also, take a look at this link : [Codes: what not to do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do).

Comment: Found it in the question paper of a puzzling contest of my college's tech fest.

Comment: The mentioning of *"Indus Valley Civilization"* would hint at the [Indus script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indus_script), but since it's still undeciphered and doesn't use latin characters to encrypt like this one, I assume it's a red herring or a subtle hint I don't yet get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a simple transposition cipher. If you split the characters into 5 rows of 5, you get this:

> `H Y Y R E`
>     `U H U T X`
>     `R U P H T`
>     `R R F E :`
>     `A R O N D`

You can then read the deciphered message from the columns, working from left to right:

> `HURRAY HURRY UP FOR THE NEXT :D`